# App is not using Store Kit API properly

Tags: cocoa, storekit, in-app-purchase

I have an app in review that has been rejected, motivation says:

> 2.2
>       The app is still not using the Store Kit API properly. It is not grabbing the pricing information from the App Store's server (see screenshot).
>   Using Store Kit, the application should send a request to the App Store to retrieve a list of product identifiers that are currently available for purchase. Once the application receives this list, it should display only those products that are flagged as available for purchase. The application is not making this request to the App Store and is instead displaying products that are returned directly by your server.

this is the screenshot

[image]

I really don't understand what I need to do... to me it seams that everything is working fine and I also don't understand why they say that "products are returned directly by my server"... it is not like that.... I will show you my code:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    if(response.products.count > 0)
{
    SKProduct* product;

    for(int i = 0; i<response.products.count; i++)
    {
        product = [response.products objectAtIndex:i];

        if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.mySite.MyApp.1"] || [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.mySite.MyApp.2"] || [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.mySite.MyApp.3"] || [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.mySite.MyApp.4"] || [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.mySite.MyApp.5"])
        {
            self.currentProduct = product;
            [self beginPaymentWithProduct:product];
        }
    }
  }
 }


- (void)beginPaymentWithProduct:(SKProduct*)product
{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}


- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}


- (IBAction)buyProduct1:(id)sender
{
   if([self canMakePurchases])
   {
     self.prodottoScelto = @"1";
    [moneteAcquistateLabel setStringValue:@"25"];
    ualRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet   setWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"com.mySite.MyApp.1", nil]]];
    [ualRequest setDelegate:self];
    [ualRequest start];
    }

}


 - (IBAction)buyProduct2:(id)sender
  {
    //same code as below
  }


  - (IBAction)buyProduct3:(id)sender
     {
      //same code as below
     }


   - (IBAction)buyProduct4:(id)sender
     {
      //same code as below
     }


    - (IBAction)buyProduct5:(id)sender
    {
      //same code as below
     }



      - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
        {
          for (SKPaymentTransaction* transaction in transactions) {
           if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {


            //    NSLog(@"Transaction Purchased: %@", transaction);

            // Make purchase available to the user, etc...

           //assegno le monete acquistate all'utente
            if ([prodottoScelto isEqual:@"1"])
              {                
            //  NSLog(@"prodotto 1 sbloccato");
            [self aggiornaMonete:25];
        }
        else if ([prodottoScelto isEqual:@"2"])
        {
            //  NSLog(@"prodotto 2 sbloccato");
            [self aggiornaMonete:60];
        }
        else if ([prodottoScelto isEqual:@"3"])
        {
            //  NSLog(@"prodotto 3 sbloccato");
            [self aggiornaMonete:105];
        }
        else if ([prodottoScelto isEqual:@"4"])
        {
            //  NSLog(@"prodotto 4 sbloccato");
            [self aggiornaMonete:160];
        }
        else if ([prodottoScelto isEqual:@"5"])
        {
            //  NSLog(@"prodotto 5 sbloccato");
            [self aggiornaMonete:225];
        }

        // Once that's all done...
        [queue finishTransaction:transaction];


    }
    else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {

        //NSLog(@"Transaction Failed: %@", transaction);
        // Display error to the user, using the error text in the transaction
        // This example uses NSLog, typically you'd use UIAlertView here
        //  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [transaction.error localizedDescription]);
    }
   }
  }
```

What should I add? This same code it is working fine in a iOS app...
thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reviewer assumed that you are retrieving the products list from your server but in reality your products are actually hardcoded into your app. Obviously he just guessed.

Anyways you are supposed to retrieve a list of products from the app store and display the **price values from the store** in your app. I guess this is just to make sure that there are no inconsistencies between the products you created in itunesconnect and the ones you offer in the app. There's a nice sequence diagram for this "built-in product model": [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1)

So I would use `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` to update or create the view that show the items for sale:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSArray *skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct *skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }
}
```

But before that you'll have to tell the app store what you products you are expecting (built-in product model):

```
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.makemyday.appy.product", nil]];
productsRequest.delegate = someObjectProbablySelf;
[productsRequest start];
```

Now someone can buy a product with price and title from the store:

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];    
}
```

Moreover you should assign some object to observe the transaction queue to monitor finished or failed transactions, one that implements the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:someObjectProbablySelf];
```

These are just the most important snippets that I collected from this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) (for iOS but for OSX it should be fine too).

Why is it working for iOS? It could be that the reviewer for your iOS app just didn't notice.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your answer... I will give it a try tomorrow... as at this time my working time is over... thx again... will let you know if it worked. Peace Massy

Comment: Sorry user511 but I have no clear how to integrate your code with my code.... as you can see I have multiple products... could you please show me where to put your code and how to have all the 5 products?
I know I'm asking a lot but I'm really lost with this matter... and would appreciate a lot your effort...
Thansk a lot... Massy

Comment: I would just add it to your existing code or put it all into an own singleton class that manages the in app purchase. Regarding your 5 products: Add them to the `NSSet` initializer in the `SKProductsRequest` initializer. (You should really check out the tutorial link at the end of my answer. There you'll find a step-by-step guide.)